# Async load modules via knockoutjs with webpack

Tags: knockout.js, webpack, webpack-2

I am currently setting up a knockoutjs project with webpack. One of the main aspects I want to achieve is lazy loading of bundles. While I have been able to achieve code splitting it currently requires the app to specifically contain code for this and I would like to get rid of this specific code as I believe knockoutjs already comes with the necessary infrastructure.

During app setup, components are registered in knockoutjs like this:

```
ko.components.register('form-page', { require: 'components/form-page/form' });
```

Knockout will load the referenced module with an async require only of the component form-page is used.

With my webpack setup, this will fail because

- Webpack does not detect that there is a dependency on components/form-page/form
- Module names are mangled by webpack to some short identifier, so the components/form-page/form is unknown at runtime

Ideally I would get webpack to detect this as an async module dependency, but in a first step it would be sufficient to declare the modules I want to have available in the webpack config while preserving the module names, letting ko require its dependencies as it needs it.

Any idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that I've not yet found a way to do this dynamically.
Here's an alternative way of doing it though.

**src/components/Input/Input.js**

example component

```
import ko from 'knockout';
import FormComponent from '../../../classes/FormComponent';

class InputControl extends FormComponent {
  constructor(params) {
    super(params);
  }
}

ko.components.register('input-control', {
  viewModel: InputControl,
  template: require('./Input.html')
})
```

**src/components/index.js**

Using webpack built-in stuff loop through each component folder to pick up the ko.components.register

```
const components = require.context('./', true, /\.js$/);

components.keys().forEach(function(component) {
  const componentName = component.substr(2);
  require('./' + componentName);
});
```

**src/app.js**

It's important that components get registered before the applyBindings happens otherwise ko isn't going to know about them.

```
require("./components");

var PageModel = function() {...}
model = new PageModel();

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Basically create all your components and include them all at once. Works with hot module replacement and what not. Usually pretty lightweight too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom component loader https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html

```
var myloader =  {
    loadComponent: function (name, componentConfig, callback) {
        if (!componentConfig.import) {
            callback(null);
            return;
        }


        componentConfig.import()
            // Using the defaultLoader so we can support the different component configs knockout supports by default
            .then(config => ko.components.defaultLoader.loadComponent(name, config, callback));
    }
}
```

And add it to the knockout loaders. Using `unshift` so it's the first loader hit

```
ko.components.loaders.unshift(myloader);
```

Now your component registration is changed to

```
ko.components.register('form-page', { import: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "form-page" */'components/form-page/form') });
```

This takes advantage of Webpack's [lazy loading](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/). Though be aware that dynamic imports need some additional babel plugins.

The webpackChunkName comment tells webpack what to name the js file it outputs.